# How to select the "selected Date" in asp:Calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

The question sounds illogical, but it is not:

I have 2 dates "Target" and "Actual". Usually the "Actual" date is very close to "Target", but not necessarily to the current date. To avoid the multiple clicks in the calendar that would navigate you to the month/year of interest, I set the selected date to my "Target" date when it is opened. This works great, BUT does not allow me to select that day, with the calendar closing automatically after selecting.

Any idea to solve this or any known alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Calendar1 component, you can use a code like:

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
Calendar1.TodaysDate = tomorrow;
Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
```

When this calendar changed **SelectionChanged** the selected date, you can set the other calendar.

Tell me if you need more detail.

Comment: But then I would not be able to select tomorrows date, as it is already selected?! Anyway, you gave me the best hint which is changing the TodaysDate parameter to the "Target" date and do completely without setting the SelectedDate